# How to change the textStyle of Stepper in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) and I am trying to change the color and textStyle inside the Step (yellow circle) widget (i.e: 1,2,3) from white to black.
This is my code:

```
Theme(
              data: ThemeData(
                primaryColor: kGold,
                canvasColor: kDarkBlue,
              ),
              child: new Stepper(
                steps: spr,
                type: StepperType.horizontal,
                currentStep: _currentstep,
                onStepTapped: _showcontent,
              )),
```

This is the output:
[image]

Comment: I guess the only way is to make a custom class

Comment: Can you add your spr. You can probably just change the textstyle for every widget in spr.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the textStyle from spr

Answer (score 0):

(April 2022) Right now colors are hardcoded in the widget.

I've submitted the issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102558

For a now the only way is to copy a widget and use your own colors.